# How to select a speicifc colum and row in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

The CSV file looks like this

`,1,2,3,4,5
1,ITN122A,ITN122A,ICJ122A,SCI092F,DIG102A
2,DIG102A,PIA072C,ENC112A,DIG102A,VBS112A
3,ITN112A,ENC112A,ITN112A,ICJ122A,ITN122A
4,DIG092A,ICJ122A,ITN122A,DIG092A,ITN121A
5,SCI092H,DIG092A,DIG102A,ITN112A,ICJ122A`

What I want to do is select a specific row and column from the CSV and set it as a variable to then write that data to other csv file.

For example, if it was Monday and 12:20pm it would select row 1 (for Monday) and column 4 (for 12:20pm) so it would select `DIG092A` and then write that data to another csv file.

I know you can select rows and print the whole row/column but how do I select a specific one.

Thank you :)

Comment: This site can help you write code, but we don't typically write code for you.  Can you include what you have so far?

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best way to do it, but I have approached similar situations by reading through each line in the CSV and adding it to a big list of rows. Like this:

```
import csv
dataList = []
with open('yourfile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
  csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
  for row in csvreader:
     dataList.append(row)
csvfile.close()
```

Then you can access each row and column with regular python list indexing. For example, in your example, you could go:

`dataList[2]`

and get

`[2,DIG102A,PIA072C,ENC112A,DIG102A,VBS112A]`

or

`dataList[2][2]`

and get

`PIA072C`

Then write to your new csv file as described in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

**Edit**

As discussed in the comments, you can make it use days of the week and your P2 by adding this to the bottom of it:

```
Monday = 1
P2 = 2

print(dataList[Monday][P2])
```

with your data, it should print:

`ITN122A`

Note that Python starts counting at zero, so "column 2" is actually the third column across. If that's confusing, maybe read up on list indexing in Python. [This](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists) looks like a good introduction.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am new to python and this is very helpful

Comment: how do I now print that data so I can see it, I've tried just `print dataList[2][2]` but it jut gives me a error

Comment: Are you using python 3? Then you have to make it `print(dataList[2][2])`

Comment: is it possible to use variables instead ?? so `dataList[Monday[P2]` and have `Monday = 1` `P2= 2` ect??

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\attendance\Class.py", line 5, in <module>
    for row in csvreader:
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)` I get this error when I run it using `print(dataList[2][2])`

Comment: Yes, you could make `Monday` a variable with value 1 and `P2` equal to 2 and then go `dataList[Monday][P2]`, which will be the same as `dataList[1][2]`.

Comment: Sorry there were two errors in my answer before. It should say `with open('yourfile.csv', 'r')`, not `with open('yourfile.csv', 'rb')`, and it should say `dataList.append(row)`, not `dataList.append[row]`. I have fixed both of these in the answer above, it should work now.